# Yii model is validating but data could not be saved

Tags: yii

I have a yii application. Data is validated properly. the `$model->validate()` returns true but data is not being saved. Is there any way that I know about the error. It does nothing. neither prints error nor any warning.

```
if (isset($_POST['Invoice'])) {
    $model->validate();
    $model->attributes = $_POST['Invoice'];
    if (!$model->validate()) {
        die(CVarDumper::dump($model->errors,10,true));
    }

    if ($model->save()) {
        die("Data saved");
        $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
    } else {
        CVarDumper::dump($model->attributes,10,true);
        CVarDumper::dump($model->errors,10,true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at those answers, maybe your cause of error is in one them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If save() is returning true and there are no errors as such in your database and queries. Only thing, thats possible is you haven't marked some of the column safe for mass assignment via "$model->attributes".

Make sure the column you are trying to save are marked safe in the "rules" function in your model. You can mark columns safe via adding the following rule in "rules" function in the model.

```
  array ( "column_name1, column_name2 ....." , "safe" )
```

Answer (score 9):

if you override `beforeSave` or `afterFind` method in your model,

```
public function beforeSave() {
    return true; //don't forget this
}

public function afterFind() {
    return true; //don't forget this
}
```

make sure you **return true** for those function

Answer (score 5):

I've just ran into something similar to this. Everything was validating correctly, and $model->save() was returning true, but no data was saved in the database.

The problem and solution was that I was creating the $model object like so:

```
$model = ClassName::model();
```

but you need to create the object like so:

```
$model = new ClassName;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It was really a life saver. I was fighting for it since one day and finally your answer solved my problem. Many many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you have this problem, you replace this:

```
$model->save(false)
```

This solves your problem.

If you use `$model->save();` the filters is running that is not good for you.

Comment: This is totally wrong! Using this code you will save the model without validating it! http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail

Answer (score 1):

Fire up some [logging](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging) and see what going on...

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you are doing an AR `save()` in the `$model->save()` method. You do not get any error, but the data is not saved as well. 
If this is the case you would like to do a:

```
die(CVarDumper::dump($arObj->errors,10,true));
```

after the `$arObj->save();` call. Most of the time this happens because of the Database rejecting the values provided for insert or update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my mistake was with the post name in the controller, where I used `$model->save`. I had given wrong - `if(isset($_POST['postname']))`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I was using reCaptcha. I just did this and it worked:

`$model->scenario = NULL;`

Make sure you do this AFTER validation.

Answer (score 0):

Also **do not** override your model constructor:

`function __construct() { } // don't do this`

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I had a property for the column name in the ActiveRecord class, so it wasn't saving.

You should not declare properties for column names as I guess the magic methods `__get()` and `__set()` are used to save data, I guess by checking if there are column changes when you click the `save()` method to avoid useless SQL queries. In my case, because the column was a user-declared property, it wasn't in the columns list and therefore changes to it were not detected.

Hope this helps other people